# jQuery caching of selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know if I am using a selector more than once its better to cache it in a javascript variable.  What if I want to perform the same action on multiple jQuery selectors that are stored in variables?  ex

```
var $selector1 = $('#div1');
var $selector2 = $('#div2');
var $selector3 = $('#div3');
//do some work here on each individual div

//now I want to do this
$('#div1, #div2, #div3').addClass('myClass');
```

Is there a way to do that on the 3 variables? (something like
`($selector1, $selector2, $selector3).addClass('myClass');`)

Comment: If you want to execute certain action on unknown number if elements. Keep stacking them into an array and then use $.each() to execute that action. Hope this helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$selector1.add($selector2).add($selector3).addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$selector1.add($selector2).add($selector3).addClass('myClass');
```